# Name for purposefully bad gifts

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-meaning

Is there a name or phrase for a purposefully bad/evil gift? I can think of white elephant or gag gifts but I don't think either of these quite work. For example, you purposely purchased a CD of an artist that the person hates as a gift for a coworker you can't stand or gave your brother socks for Christmas out of spite. I wonder if this exists in other languages?

Comment: Do you want a name for the type of gift or for the act of giving them?

Comment: Trojan horse / poison chalice/ double edge sword are in above question.